# What means Nanfu? (Characters identified: 阿難)

Tags: characters, classical-chinese

A friend of mine bought that stone a while ago

[image]

With the help of a friend, we were about to determine that the words in [small seal script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script) means (from left to right) [難](https://ctext.org/dictionary.pl?if=en&char=%E9%9B%A3) (difficult) and [阜](https://ctext.org/dictionary.pl?if=en&char=%E9%98%9C) (plentiful).

Combine together, it seems to go with Nanfu.

What does it mean at the time and is there still a meaning today?

Comment: 阿難,  ananda? is it on the base of an statue?

Comment: Hi @水巷孑蠻, yes it is.

Comment: should be him as @水巷孑蠻 mentioned: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%80nanda

Comment: Dear @水巷孑蠻, can please write an answer? I'll accept it.

Comment: @andy k ,done, do you have photos of the whole statue?

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 my friend should send the whole pic soon, if she does not forget... (but that's another story)

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 one additional question: Is reading from right to left, the old form of writing, please? The current form seems to me, to be from left to right.

Comment: yes, everything before fourth may movement (1919) should be read from right to left, top to bottom.

Comment: Thank you @水巷孑蠻

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all, read from right to left.

the right character, the left component is (阜, ⻖) is easy to recognise. the right component is a 口 (mouth) with surrounding stroke, so, it’s also easy to guess that it’s 阿 (u+963f)

then, confirm the guess with [漢語多功能字庫](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/)

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=阿](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E9%98%BF)

the left character, well, it’s also “easy” to find that it’s 難 (u+96e3)

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=難](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E9%9B%A3)

put them together, the word is “阿難” ananda, one of the ten principle disciple of buddha.

further, judging from the photo provided, i think the characters are inscribed on a stone plinth, of a statue; that’s why i ask in the comment.

have fun :)